# 'I wouldn't vote for Clinton if you paid me': what does this mean?

Tags: meaning

My understanding was that a sentence of the form:

> I won't do X if Y happens

means something along the lines of

> if Y happens I will not do X

Nigel Farage stated in [a speech](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/aug/24/nigel-farage-donald-trump-rally-hillary-clinton)  *'I wouldn't vote for Clinton if you paid me'*. To my mind, this seems to be saying *'If you pay me, I will not vote for Clinton'*, but obviously he didn't mean that. What was the meaning he intended to convey?

Note: the full quote is

> “I will say this: if I was an American citizen, I wouldn’t vote for Hillary Clinton if you paid me!”

Comment: I kind of already just made the assumption and changed it, since it's tangential to the actual question. Separate from that, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional is a fuller examination of "if-then" statements. It's also not really germane, but could be useful.

Comment: When this kind of sentence is spoken, there is invariably a word or phrase in the if-clause which receives heavy emphasis. Here it would be **paid**.  It means, You could even PAY me and I would not vote for him. Compare: She wouldn't go out with him if he were the **last man on earth**.

Comment: @JonathanGarber It's shocking that my question is tangential, anyway, after your edit the question looks really good! It is reflecting what I wanted to ask, thank you!

Comment: @shintaroid, no, not at all, I meant that who was being named was irrelevant to the underlying question, not that your question was irrelevant!

Comment: @JonathanGarber Alright, whatever, the question looks really good now, thanks!

Comment: Yes @JonathanGarber who the quote mentions is not relevant to the grammatical construction, but one can't change a *direct quote*.

Comment: "would" != "will". I think that's the source of your confusion.

Comment: Note also that it'd be illegal to accept payment in return for a particular vote. So the literal meaning of the syllogism, "I would not not get involved in a criminal scheme if someone offered monetary inducement" is a lot weaker than the idiomatic meaning of "not if you paid me"! He doesn't mean you to take into account that perhaps the illegality is the reason he wouldn't do it...

Comment: @AlanCarmack, I see what you mean, yes. I wasn't thinking of it in terms of being a direct quote, but you're right, a quote should clearly indicate any elision, which I didn't do.

Comment: It's a basic failure of logic rather than language: "not A if B" does not imply "A if not B".

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> I wouldn't vote for Clinton if you paid me

The use of **would** and **paid** are examples of [backshifts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101626/conditional-present-or-past/101629#101629), which indicate that this is a hypothetical condition, not a real one. Furthermore, **not if you paid me** is a [well-known idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+if+you+paid+me) meaning **under no circumstances**.

The bit that makes the meaning clear is an implied **even**

> I wouldn't vote for Clinton  **even** if you paid me.

What it now means is that under any and all circumstances, even if you were to offer me money to do it, I would not vote for Clinton.

Comment: Is 'even' always possible to be applied in 'I won't do X if Y happens'? that is, can I understand it like 'I won't do X if Y happens' equals 'I won't do X even if Y happens'?

Comment: It's not always possible. For example "I won't go to watch the soccer game if it is raining" implies that I *will* go to watch the game if it is *not* raining. The original quote means "I will *never* vote for Clinton, whatever you do to try to persuade (or bribe) me".

Comment: The key is that being paid to do X is considered a positive inducement to do X. So, saying you won't do something _if paid_ means that _even being paid to do it_ is not sufficient incentive, which means you _really_ don't want to do it. If Y happening is anything other than a positive inducement, this relationship doesn't hold.

Comment: Good answer, except I would delete "under any and all circumstances". We should leave room for stronger versions such as "I would not do X if you put a gun to my head."

Comment: @shintaroid yeah, it all rests on the understanding that, normally, to get someone to do something that isn't enjoyable, you have to pay them. if someone won't do something even when paid, then it's *really* unpleasant. people play hypothetical games with this a lot: e.g., "How much money would you need to get to be willing to do X?" "Is there anything you wouldn't do no matter how large the payment?"

Comment: Should not it say **If I were an American** as in subjunctive mood expressing a hope? And it should also have **if you would pay me**?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh, it should be **were**, but **was** is widely used in informal speech. **if you would pay me** is the hypothetical version of **if you will pay me**, which is not correct. **if you paid me** is the hypothetical version of **if you pay me**, which is correct. Note the backshifting: pay->paid.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh I don't think it's expressing a hope (as in the person hopes to become an American citizen), though "were" is still better grammatically. I think in this context it's just setting up a hypothetical situation: the person speaking is not an American citizen, but if they were, they wouldn't vote for Hillary even someone attempted to bribe them.

Comment: @shintaroid, TTY add to alephzero's explanation, the subjunctive form *wouldn't* is really important for this meaning. "I *won't* do X *even if* you pay me" sounds odd; it would probably be understood as hyperbole, but it's not idiomatic. And "I won't do X if you pay me" sounds like an extortion demand: "I won't tell the police/your wife/Mom if you pay me."

Comment: I myself wouldn't vote for any politician if someone bribed me to do it, but that is probably not what Mr. Farage meant.

Comment: @gnasher729 I doubt even he knows what he meant. Given the acuity of Farange's intellect (for instance, see these [**gems**](http://www.livemaguk.com/10-outrageous-ukip-blunders/),) he would have long ago quit reading this Q & A and gone back to poring over the football scores.

Answer (score 8):

The headline gives only part of the sentence. The full sentence, as reported in *[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/aug/24/nigel-farage-donald-trump-rally-hillary-clinton)*,  is

> “I will say this: if I was an American citizen, I wouldn’t vote for Hillary Clinton if you paid me!”

We can isolate the conditional sentence as

> If I was an American citizen, I wouldn’t vote for Hillary Clinton if you paid me.

This is a typical conditional construction which uses the past simple  form (here: *was*)  in the *if-clause* and a modal (here: *would* in *wouldn't vote*) to indicate an unreal condition (sometimes called irrealis). Farage is not an American citizen, but this sentence talks about what he would not do if he was an American citizen.

The clause *if you paid me* is still in irrealis mode since it's in the past tense. Here *if* means *even if*.

So,  the structure of the headline part of the quote  is

> I wouldn't do X, (even) if Y happened.

or, the reverse:

> (Even) if Y happened, I wouldn't do X.

See also Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage* 261.10: **If**, meaning **'even if'**

> We can use 'if' to mean 'even if'.
>
> > I'll finish this job if it takes all night.
> >
> > I wouldn't marry you if you were the last man in the world.

Except taken from ['if', meaning 'even if'. Why would ommision occur in some cases?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22577/if-meaning-even-if-why-would-ommision-occur-in-some-cases)

Comment: I don't think the "If I was an American citizen" part is really relevant. For example, Donald Trump, who _is_ an American citizen, might say "I wouldn't vote for Clinton if you paid me", with exactly the same meaning as the part of Farage's sentence that's being asked about.

Comment: "even" is omitted from "...vote for Clinton if you..." (and is technically redundant in this context) because it is implied by the strong condition "if you paid me".

Comment: Since you mention the phrase "If I was an American citizen..." and discuss its use of the simple past we should point that in standard literary English this would be "If I were an American citizen...". Note to Captain Obvious: Yes, I am describing prescriptive grammar.

Answer (score 5):

As others have correctly pointed out, there is an implied "even" in this sentence. This expression is part of a family of similar expressions. In them the speaker expresses his strong disinclination to do something by naming some kind of inducement or modification of the task which would make it more necessary or palatable. Examples:

> I would not do that to save my life.
>
> I would not do that if they put a gun to my head.
>
> I would not touch it with a ten foot pole.
>
> I would not do that for all the gold in Christendom.

In each case the speaker is saying that the condition is insufficient to make him do the thing he is disinclined to do.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with everyone who said there is an implied "even."

I suspect part of the reason is the Imperfect Subjunctive.  It is used when you want to imply that something would never happen. (http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/98)

In this case, the "paid" in "If you paid me" is in the imperfect subjunctive.  This is similar to the use of "were" in "If I were you."

Disclaimer: Then again, it could just be idiomatic/ironic, which is the case with "am" in "and I'm the King of England," which is used also to convey veiled rejection.

Comment: No. It is not the imperfect subjunctive. That is something that Spanish and other Romance languages have. English does not not have either one, in the sense the those languages do. English has ways of talking about ***irrealis***. There is no reason to resort to terms from Spanish to explain an Engish construction. 'If you paid me' is the past tense form (*paid*) expressing *irrealis*.

Comment: For instance, see this on the [so-called imperfect](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/78340/299240).